# Writing Collections.addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements) without wildcard

Tags: java, generics

Currently, I'm learning java generics. I have question related to  Collections.addAll()

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements) {
  boolean result = false;
  for (T element : elements)
    result |= c.add(element);
  return result;
}
```

Why do we use lower bounded wildcard? can't we remove it?

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c, T... elements) {
  boolean result = false;
  for (T element : elements)
    result |= c.add(element);
  return result;
}
```

What is the affect of replacing `Collection<? super T>` with `Collection<T>` in this case?

Comment: We can't remove it! A very illuminating contribution to the topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection<? super T>` allows you call the method on a `Collection` that contains elements of any supertype of `T`. So if you have a bunch of objects of the `WholeNumber` class and you want to add them to a variable of type `Collection<WholeNumber>`, both would work. But if you have a `Collection<RealNumber>`, you wouldn't be able to do the second addAll method, since `RealNumber` and `WholeNumber` are different, even though it makes sense to a person that a WholeNumber can be part of a list of `RealNumbers`. Since Java is invariant, the first `? super T` allows more flexibility, without you having to typecast things.

Comment: Please use backticks to format code, in the future. The `<>`s used for Java generics got confused with HTML tags and made your answer appear wrong until I used backticks to fix it.